# When I try to input a string that contains spaces it's supposed to go to the error message, it does not do that?

Tags: c

when I try to input a string that contains a semi colon it goes to the error message( please enter a string without any spaces) similarly if I try to enter a string with spaces it still goes to the error message.

what my program should do is if the input does not contain a space run the program else go to the error message.If the input contains a semi colon but no spaces run the program.

```
     printf("Enter a string\n");
     scanf("%20s", string_buffer);

     stringp1 = string_buffer;
```

Comment: Remove the `&` here `if (strstr(&stringp1, " ") != 0)` --> `if (strstr(stringp1, " ") != 0)` but for a single char `strchr` is better.

Comment: I didn't post an answer, I was pointing out some faults.

Comment: yh I didnt get warning when i did that thanks

Comment: By the way do you guys get paid for answering questions

Comment: No we don't. Stop being so rude to people trying to help. I'm out of here.

Comment: @Weather Vane My SO pay went up 25% - Didn't you get the annual pay bump?. (0.0 + 0.0*25% --> 0.0)

Comment: @chux I heard that your SO pay doubles once you get to 5000 reputation

Comment: Want to see the first thing that's wrong with your code? Enter 20 or more non-blank characters and you'll find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `scanf("%20s", string_buffer);`

   Use `fgets` instead of `scanf` as `%s` in `scanf` matches a sequence of non-white-space characters only.

   So if you enter `foo bar`, it will only accept `foo` and not the whole string.

---

2. `if (strstr(&stringp1, " ") != 0)`

   `strstr` expects both arguments to be `char *` and here first argument is `char**`.

   Remove `&` *address of* operator.

---

3. `if (strstr(&stringp1, " ") != 0)`

   If substring is found then `strstr` returns `char *` pointer to substring else it returns `NULL`.

   That means this `if` expression will be true if there's a white space in the string. And we want an error message to be printed for that. So clearly reverse condition.

   Solution:  change that `if` to

   `if (!strstr(stringp1, " "))`

---

So the correct code snippet would be:

```
...
printf("Enter a string\n");
fgets(string_buffer, 20, stdin);

stringp1 = string_buffer;

if (!strstr(stringp1, " ")) {
...
```

Answer (score 2):

The format specifier `%s` doesn't read blank spaces at all. Let's take a look at this code snippet:

```
scanf("%s", string);    
puts(string);
```

Input :

> Hello, my name is Claudio

The output will be :

> Hello,

To avoid that you should use an inverted group scansion inside of your scanf instruction, just like this one :

```
scanf("%string_size[^\n]", string);
```

This will do the trick.

By the way, I would advise you to use other function like getline or fgets to take string from stdin.

Answer (score 1):

Note that scanf will break at spaces.  So, if you have this code:

```
scanf("%20s", string_buffer);
```

And you enter "hello there" is the input, then the contents of string_buffer will be only "hello".

Comment: That doesn't quite answer my question

Comment: If you want to read a string that contains embedded spaces into a buffer, you probably want to use fgets using stdin as the file pointer. Is that pointing you in the right direction?

Comment: @Anonymous Penguin Your post has no question.  Clearly posting a question will likely generate clearer answers.

Comment: I edited it now with a question hopefully that will generate some more answers

Comment: All you did was change the title to the "Australian Interrogative Inflection"?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    char string_buffer[20];
    char *stringp;

    printf("Enter a string\n");
    scanf("%19[^\n]", string_buffer);//20 --> 19, include space

    stringp = string_buffer;
    if (strstr(stringp, " ") == NULL) {//!= --> ==
        printf("Converted semicolon to 4 spaces\n");
        for (; *stringp; stringp++) {
            if (*stringp == ';'){//strsep is not needed
                printf("    ");
            } else {
                printf("%c", *stringp);
            }
        }
    } else {
        printf("Please enter a string without any spaces\n");
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```